# How can I export innerHtml of any element to Microsoft word in angular?Using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have a modal which is displaying a letter I want to export that letter to Microsoft Word. I have created a modal class in which I am calling the values from the list I want the user to give an option so that the whole thing inside modal can be exported to Microsft Word.As I am displaying a letter in Modal

Please do find my Modal

```html
<ng-template #template> <div class="modal-header"> <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Letter</h4> <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> </div> <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let item of items"> {{item}} </div> </ng-template
```

Comment: Hi Aditya Please be little more descriptive. Show us what you done!

Comment: <ng-template #template> <div class="modal-header"> <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Letter</h4> <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> </div> <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let item of items"> {{item}} </div> </ng-template> 
I have created a modal class in which I am calling the values from the list I want the user to give an option so that the whole thing inside modal can be exported to Microsft Word.As I am displaying a letter in Modal –

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Angular 2 to generate a Docx Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666367/using-angular-2-to-generate-a-docx-files)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to export content from Angular application as MS Word file

Then refer this question: [Using Angular 2 to generate a Docx Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666367/using-angular-2-to-generate-a-docx-files) to generate .docx using https://docx.js.org/#/

Comment: <ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Letter</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"   *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</ng-template>

Comment: I have created a modal class in which I am calling the values from the list I want the user to give an option so that the whole thing inside modal can be exported to Microsft Word.As I am displaying a letter in Modal

Comment: you want to export to MS Word instance or as a Word file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a simple 'HTML dump' to Word and have control over the data, have a look at docx; https://docx.js.org/#/

**From their [docs](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx)**

> Here is an example of docx working in Angular:
>   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afvxtz